# Is it possible to show pie chart if all data are 0

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using Google Visualization API for showing Pie chart.

Is it possible to show a Pie chart if all data are 0?

Comment: if its zero what u want be represented via chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot, and this because of the very nature of the pie chart. A pie chart angle is calculated (in degrees) by the following formula `(value/total)*360`. Since it is impossible to divide by zero, you cannot get the angle, and so you cannot get a pie chart, with google or any other tool, if the total of your data is 0.

So to answer to your problem, I would suggest you check the total of your values and then simply disable the pie chart if your total is equal to zero. I do not know this API in details, but i guess you might even be able to catch an exception.